# Как называется этот view?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

[image: скриншот]

Нашел в одном гайде такой view, но там не было сказано, как он называеся. В исходном коде также не нашел его название.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это если я правильно понял обычный ViewPager для перелистывания фрагментов. Добавить можно так в xml:

```
<androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager>
```

вот что должно по итогу получится после необходимых манипуляций с активностью:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Вот документация](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-swipe-view) по данному виджету. [Туториал](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/views/viewpager.php) для добавления. Так же есть ViewPager2 про который вы можете почитать [в этой статье](https://habr.com/ru/post/447406/),  в [доках](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/viewpager2) и в [туториале](https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/exploring-the-view-pager-2-86dbce06ff71)